# How to display image in ionic 4 using angular js

Tags: angular, ionic4

[image]I am using ionic 4.How to make image appear in a list.Here is my ionic code and hello-ionic.t angular script code.

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-item *ngFor="let item of items">
    <ion-thumbnail slot="start">
      <ion-img [src]="item.src"></ion-img>
    </ion-thumbnail>
    <ion-label>{{item.text}}</ion-label>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

This is hello-ionic.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-hello-ionic',
  templateUrl: 'hello-ionic.html'
})
export class HelloIonicPage {
  constructor() {

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your hello-ionic.ts

```
        import { Component } from '@angular/core';

        @Component({
          selector: 'page-hello-ionic',
          templateUrl: 'hello-ionic.html'
        })
        export class HelloIonicPage {
          constructor() {

          }

         items = [{
  src:"https://imgd.aeplcdn.com/1056x594/ec/79/85/9802/img/ol/Lamborghini-Aventador-Front-view-52648.jpg?v=201711021421&q=80",
  text:"dwa"},{src:"https://imgd.aeplcdn.com/1056x594/ec/79/85/9802/img/ol/Lamborghini-Aventador-Front-view-52648.jpg?v=201711021421&q=80",
  text:"dwa"},{src:"https://imgd.aeplcdn.com/1056x594/ec/79/85/9802/img/ol/Lamborghini-Aventador-Front-view-52648.jpg?v=201711021421&q=80",
  text:"dwa"},{src:"https://imgd.aeplcdn.com/1056x594/ec/79/85/9802/img/ol/Lamborghini-Aventador-Front-view-52648.jpg?v=201711021421&q=80",
  text:"wda"}];

       }
```

This 'items' array is referred to in your ngFor loop in your html. it takes each object and looks for its src property and feeds it to your ion img tag here `[src]="item.src"`

comment if this needs clarification

Comment: sorry .Image is not getting displayed

Comment: @sobha what do you mean by .Image ?

Comment: i am only get dwa displayed as text.I am not getting image displayed along with text

Comment: util.js:66 Ionic Native: tried calling StatusBar.styleDefault, but Cordova is not available. Make sure to a) run in a real device or simulator and b) include cordova.js in your index.html

Comment: @sobha that doesn't sound related to this. may be a problem with the image links, have you tryed other images ? are you testing on a browser ?

Comment: <ion-img [src]="item.src"></ion-img> this  line is not working

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of what's displaying ?

Comment: i have added the image

Comment: @sobha Ive updated the images in my answer see if that works?

Comment: Is it possible there's css removing it ? you could try inspecting the ion-thumbnail element in chrome dev tools